How to digitize large set of 3D points in 2D and compute the mean in 3rd axis to get a 2D image
Here is a working Python snippet that get some 3D points (see pts array) and project them on a 2D image Npix x Npix keeping on the "j,i" pixel the mean of the third axis of all "pts" that are collected to that pixel. The code is probably clear.
I have bored the way by googling some times ago.
Now, my problem is that I have a huge amount of 3D pts that are on several files (numpy arrays) and I should collect them to produce a 50,000 x 50,000 pixels image.
In a certain sense, I should make a loop on the files and accumulate on each "j,i" bin/pixel and then divide by the number of pts collected on each bin/pixel.
May be one has a super idea :)
Thanks
%pylab inline
import numpy as np
import random

params= {
 'd': 5.35,
 'halfWidth': 5.0,
 'resol': 0.1,
 'max_prof': 1000
}

resol = params['resol']; # image resolution 
d = params['d'];
halfWidth = params['halfWidth'];
centre = -d/2;
Ximgmin = centre - halfWidth;
Ximgmax = centre + halfWidth;
Yimgmin = -halfWidth;
Yimgmax = halfWidth;
Zimgmin = 0;
Zimgmax = params['max_prof'];
(Ximgmin, Ximgmax, Yimgmin, Yimgmax, Zimgmin,Zimgmax)


xrange = (Ximgmin-0.1, Ximgmax+0.1)
yrange = (Yimgmin-0.1, Yimgmax+0.1)
zrange = (0, Zimgmax)
Npts= 10_000
points = []
[ points.append(np.array([random.uniform(*xrange), 
                          random.uniform(*yrange), 
                          random.uniform(*zrange)])) for i in range(Npts) ]

pts = np.array(points).T
print(pts.shape)

Npix = 100

def info_arr(x):
    print(f"shape: {x.shape}, first: {x[0]}, last: {x[-1]}, min: {x.min()}, max: {x.max()}")

binsx = np.linspace(Ximgmin,Ximgmax,Npix-1,dtype=np.float32)
binsy = np.linspace(Yimgmin,Yimgmax,Npix-1,dtype=np.float32)

info_arr(binsx)
info_arr(binsy)

xmin = pts[0,:].min()
xmax = pts[0,:].max()
print(xmin,xmax)

ymin = pts[1,:].min()
ymax = pts[1,:].max()
print(ymin,ymax)

print(pts[2,:].min(),pts[2,:].max())

imin,imax=np.digitize(xmin,binsx),np.digitize(xmax,binsx)
print(imin,imax)

jmin,jmax=np.digitize(ymin,binsy),np.digitize(ymax,binsy)
print(jmin,jmax)

pts_x_id = np.digitize(pts[0,:],binsx)
pts_x_id = np.int32(pts_x_id)
pts_y_id = np.digitize(pts[1,:],binsy)
pts_y_id = np.int32(pts_y_id)

pts_id_2d = np.zeros(shape=(pts.shape[1],2),dtype=np.int32)

pts_id_2d[:,0] = pts_x_id
pts_id_2d[:,1] = pts_y_id
pts_z = pts[2,:]

sorted_idx = np.lexsort(pts_id_2d.T)

sorted_pts =  pts_id_2d[sorted_idx,:]

df1 = np.diff(sorted_pts,axis=0)

df2 = np.append([True],np.any(df1!=0,1),0)

# Get unique sorted labels
sorted_labels = df2.cumsum(0)-1

# Get labels
labels = np.zeros_like(sorted_idx)
labels[sorted_idx] = sorted_labels

# Get unique indices
unq_idx  = sorted_idx[df2]

pts_id_2d = pts_id_2d[unq_idx,:]

pts_z = np.bincount(labels, weights=pts_z)/np.bincount(labels)

pts_id_2d.shape,pts_z.shape

img = np.zeros((Npix,Npix),dtype=np.float32)

for pt,z in zip(pts_id_2d,pts_z):
    i = int(pt[0])
    j = int(pt[1])
    img[j,i]=z

imshow(img);colorbar();



What is the actual problem? The time taken? The memory usage? The current approach doe snot work? A minimal reproducible example would help (especially since the distribution matters -- the provided one is not reproducible).

Well @JérômeRichard the main problem resides in the fact that the pts should be considered as resident on several files, and if one tends to read file-by-file the pts and make the counting of points in a ij bins of the final image,  pts_z = np.bincount(labels, weights=pts_z)/np.bincount(labels)  cannot be used as one should keep all the pts_z ot per bin.  In other  words: in during the second file scan how you manage to get the right mean value in all bins that are already field by the first file scan, and so on for all the files.

Thank you for the clarification. I think it would be better to include the content of this comment in your question.

@Jean-Eric I still don't understand the problem clearly, but it seems related to computing a "running mean". Suppose for some img[j, i], file 1 gives a mean mu_1. This mean was computed by some sum_z_1/n_1, where n_1 is the number of points. When you start scanning file 2, it gives you a new mean mu_2 = sum_z_2/n_2. You can use the equality: mu = (mu_1 * n_1 + mu_2 * n_2) / (n_1 + n_2). Unfortunately, this means you need to maintain an array the same size as img. Given that you have scanned k files, you need to maintain n_k[j, i]: the number of points added to img[j, i] so far for k files.
